# Program with exceptions not compiling, how do I fix the errors?

Tags: vb.net

for my class, I am supposed to create a program that will calculate and print the volume of a cube using the variables the user inputted. It must ask the user to define all the variables. It also must also anticipate errors from the user with exceptions by using the Try, catch, and finally keywords. So if the user inputs something incorrect, it gives an error message.

I am trying to compile the program, but it does not do so.  I have "catched" dividebyzero exceptions and overflow excpetions. If someone could help me out and tell me what is wrong with my code, I would appreciate it.

```
 'This program will calculate and print the volume of a cube  using variables inputted by the user
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Cube Volume Finder, Input side length")
    Try
        Dim X As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim inttemp As Integer
        inttemp = X / 0
    Catch ex As DivideByZeroException
        Console.WriteLine("Divide by zero exception has occured")
    Finally
        System.Console.WriteLine(intTemp)
    End Try


    Try
        Dim X As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim Y As Integer
        Y = X ^ 3
    Catch Z As OverflowException
        System.Console.WriteLine("A overflow exception has occured")
    Finally
        System.Console.WriteLine(Y)
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the program")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Module
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"I am trying to compile the program, but it does not do so."` - What is the compiler error?

Comment: It tells me "Y" and "intTemp" is not declared, even though I declared it.

Comment: They are not accessible in the Finally clause, only the Try block.  That's fixable by moving their declarations out of the Try block but it not make sense whatsoever to try to display the value when the calculation failed.  Delete the Finally clauses.

Comment: Thanks! I should have realized that. Also, you are right about deleting the finally statement and I have no Idea why I even added that in there.

Comment: Why do you intentionally try to divide by zero??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable declared inside an If/Try/For/While etc... block is not visible outside that block. So your variables intTemp and Y are declared but just as your code leaves the try block they disappears. You should move the declaration before the block

Said that, the first try/catch block seems to be useless. Are you experimenting with a divide by zero exception?

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Cube Volume Finder, Input side length")
' Commented out, this is not needed to calculate the volume of a cube 
'    Dim inttemp As Integer
'    Try
'        Dim X As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
'        'inttemp = X / 0
'    Catch ex As DivideByZeroException
'        Console.WriteLine("Divide by zero exception has occured")
'    Finally
'        System.Console.WriteLine(intTemp)
'    End Try


    Dim Y As Integer
    Try
        Dim X As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
        Y = X ^ 3
    Catch Z As OverflowException
        System.Console.WriteLine("A overflow exception has occured")
    Finally
        System.Console.WriteLine(Y)
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the program")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Keep in mind that your code has a serious problem. Your project is compiled using Option Strict Off. This allows automatic conversion from strings to integers. But this is very dangerous and should be avoided.
You should always check the user input being of the correct type and values

```
Dim userInput As String = Console.ReadLine()
Dim X As Integer
If Int32.TryParse(userInput, X) Then
    Y = X ^ 3
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number!")
End If
```

Comment: Ah, I understand. Just compiled that and it works. The first try/catch block is for if the user inputted something divided by zero. Does that make sense or is there no way to implement two exceptions? Thanks!

Comment: User inputs the value X and is your code that tries the divide by zero. Really I can't understand that part. However, if you want to check the user input being a valid number you should use the Int32.TryParse method that converts a string (returned by ReadLine) in a valid integer that you can check for valid values